# problem with cancel button Triggering a workflow on file upload in document library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library

When a user clicks on Add Document, a File upload dialogue is displayed and the user browses for a file. Even though he clicks cancel button after file upload, workflow is triggering. How to avoid this behavior when user clicks on cancel button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the workflow on file modified, not file created.

Essentially, the process is: SharePoint uploads the file, then checks it out to the user who uploaded it until the required file metadata has been filled out, then update the file with the metadata.